# Flutter: how to customize app bar and change status bar color each screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

I am fixing an issue related to changing app bar color.
I have try many ways but still not achieved my purpose.

Ex: I have 3 screens
which are

1. Screen A status bar colors green
2. Screen B status bar color red
3. Screen C status bar color yellow

As figure below, I want to remove grey color from status bar.
And set specific color as mention above.
[image]

My issue,
if I put specific app bar, it does not work

```
AppBar(
       elevation: 0,
       systemOverlayStyle:
       SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.redAccent),
        ),
```

but if I put under context it works but apply that color to all app bar

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: 
    Colors.green));
    return Scafford(
     .......
    );

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`appBar` have property of `systemOverlayStyle`. You can try the below code. or there is package for changing the background of status bar.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor_ns

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
          systemOverlayStyle:
              SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.black),
        ),
```

or using the package

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    await FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.green[400]);
  }
```